# Why am I getting the error 'cannot find symbol' when I calculate cube numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, foreach

My program has a `thirdPower` method which takes a `number` as parameter and computes the *third power* (see [Cube Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_(algebra))) of all numbers from 1 to that `number`, i.e. `13, 23, ..., number3`. The method stores the computed cubes in an array, and then prints them using a foreach loop.

For example, the call

```
thirdPower(15);
```

should result in an array containing 1, 8, 27, ..., 3375.

This is my code so far, but I get the error `cannot find symbol`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         thirdPower(15);
}

private static void thirdPower(int number) {
    int[] array = new int[number];
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= getal; i++) {
        array[i] = count * count * count;
        count++;
    }

    for (int numberYe : array) {
        System.out.println(numberYe);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Few things to improve before you ask your next question. 1) Your question title *Java simple foreach program* is too generic and does not explain your problem at all. Your question title should summarize the problem, and is best to be formulated as a question. 2) Always add your programming language as the first tag to your question; in this case `java`. 3) When you get an error, always include it (the exact error message) into your question description. Other than that your description was helpful to understand what you want to do; an example together with the code is always great to have!

Comment: I also suggest that you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and ***read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)***.

Comment: Is this your original code or did you replace some variable names? To me, it looks like you forgot to replace `getal` with `number`.

Comment: @MCEmperor I agree with you – and I had the same thought during review. Also, this "problem" would be immediately obvious if the OP would use an IDE like IntelliJ or research the compiler error message a bit. Giving the OP the *benefit of the doubt* and the fact that just replacing `getal` with `number` wouldn't be 100% correct given the other code around it – I gave a complete answer ... as well as comments on how to improve this "question" and "asking" the OP to read the help pages "in good faith" that the OP will post "better" (= higher relevance for other users) questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i <= getal` in the first for-loop isn't defined anywere, so you'll get the compile-time error

```
Error:(12, 29) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable getal
```

To do what you described you should change `i <= getal` to `i < number` because you want

1. to find the 3rd power of every number from 1 up to and including the given `number`, and
2. you start your for-loop with `int i = 0` which means that the condition has to be `<` instead of `<=` as you already count the 0th-time as the first loop-iteration.

This then results into

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        thirdPower(15);
    }

    private static void thirdPower(int number) {
        int[] array = new int[number];
        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            array[i] = count * count * count;
            count++;
        }

        for (int numberYe : array) {
            System.out.println(numberYe);
        }
    }
}
```

giving the output as

```
1
8
27
64
125
216
343
512
729
1000
1331
1728
2197
2744
3375
```